# How to make pages available to users who are not logged in (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have acquired a Wordpress Multi-Site domain from another developer. One of the sites has pages that are hidden (unless the user has a login). The other site is supposed to be completely public unless purchasing an item, then it will prompt for a login. How do I make the other pages available to users who are NOT logged in.

I've looked at individual pages settings (they all say public), I've checked for Plugins that might be managing these permissions at both the individual site level and the Network level.

How can I make the pages public on the one site without affecting the other?
ANY pointers would be very helpful. I tried looking in the wordpress forums - but could not find where to  post to their community.

Comment: Without any information about your website or how it is set up, it is impossible for us to know what could be causing this. It could almost anything to do with your site - a plugin, the theme code, a server setting, even a bug. There is simply not enough information here to be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - I understand. There was a theme change. I've looked through all of the plugins but can't find any specific settings for page redirection. It is a WordPress Multisite. So one site does keep users from viewing pages if they're not logged in. But this original site is supposed to be completely public. I'm thinking that something carried over by mistake to the public site.